# Spyder module is there but "ModuleNotFoundError"

Tags: python, spyder

Here is the sample code that I was using:

```
import class3

rec3 = class3.Person('Jane', ['dev', 'mgr'], 30)

print(rec3.age)
print(rec3.info())

from class3 import Person

rec4 = Person('Mike', ['dev', 'mgr'], 35)

print(rec4.age)
print(rec4.info())
```

`class3`:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, jobs, age = None):
        self.name = name
        self.jobs = jobs
        self.age = age

    def info(self):
        return(self.name, self.jobs)

rec1 = Person('Bob', ['dev','mgr'], 40.5)
rec2 = Person('Sue', ['dev','cto'])

print(rec1.jobs)
print(rec2.jobs)
```

If the module is there, then shouldn't `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'class3'` not appear at all?

Comment: Add both modules in single package

Comment: What do you mean? Those two segments of code are in separate `.py` files

Comment: yes..you are correct

Comment: You said "If the module is there". But where is "there"?

Comment: @CarlosCordoba I meant to say that both modules are in the same file directory

Comment: What happens if you add an empty `__init__.py` file in that directory?